# Doubt on Lebesgue integration

Tags: lebesgue-integral

How to prove that $\int_{\Omega}(a+b|u|^{(p-1)})^{q}\le C\int_{\Omega}(1+|u|^{(p-1)q})$ where $ u\in L^{p}(\Omega)$, and a,b are constants. q is a conjugate exponent  of p

Comment: Any bounds on $a, b, p$, or $q$?

Comment: @marty-cohen here q is conjugate exponent of p

Answer (score -1):

Note:
This answer may show how little I know
about Lebesgue integration.
I am treating this just as
an inequality between the integrands
and assuming some bounds on the parameters.

This is true if
$(1+x^u)^v
< C(1+x^{uv})
$,
where
$x > 0$
and
$C$ depends on $u$ and $v$
and $u = [-1$ and $v = q$.

If we let $x^u = y$,
this becomes
$(1+y)^v < C(1+y^v)$,
or
$1+y < C(1+y^v)^{1/v}$,
where the $C$'s are different
and depend on $u$ and $v$.

By the arithmetic means inequality,
if $v > 1$,
$\dfrac{1+y}{2}
< \left(\dfrac{1+y^v}{2}\right)^{1/v}
$
or
$1+y
< 2^{1-1/v}(1+y^v)^{1/v}
$

So, if $p>1$ and $q > 1$,
this seems to be true.

Comment: My mystery downvoter strikes again!

Comment: I screwed up here. Could you (1) fix $u=[-1$ to $u=p-1$ and (2) change $C$ to some other letter since it's not the same $C$ as in the question? And I think "generalized means inequality" is more common than "arithmetic means inequality". I don't recall ever voting on any of your posts before, by the way.

Comment: About the parameters: The fact that $p$ and $q$ are Hölder conjugates ($1/p+1/q = 1$ and $p,q \in [1,\infty]$) and that we presumably don't want to deal with infinite exponents would imply that $p,q > 1$. And I think we would also want $a,b \geq 0$ so that their exponentiation by non-integer powers is nice.